# How to specify resolution of a plot?

Tags: plotting

Suppose I need to plot Sin function:

```
Plot[Sin[x ], {x, -10 , 10 }]
```

Now I need to specify the resolution of the plot. I tried by using list Plot

```
ListPlot[Table[Sin[x ], {x, -10, 10, 0.01}], Joined -> True]
```

But here the x axis is different. In this case it plots from 0 to 20.

Now I have two questions,

1. How to plot a function giving the specifications
2. Is there any way to use ListPlot and get the axis as (-10,10).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can make the axes agreeby inputting the {x,y} data pairs: ListPlot[Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, -10, 10, 0.01}], Joined -> True]

Comment: Are you wanting to control how many points are used to generate the plot?

Answer (score 5):

The reason `ListPlot` gives you 1 to 20 on the x-axis is that you've only specified y-values in the table. Try:

```
ListPlot[
  Table[
    {x, Sin[x]},
    {x, -10, 10, 0.1}
  ]
]
```

[image: Plot of sin(x) with correct x-axis.]

`ListPlot` expects data to be pairs of `{x, y}` coordinates. If they are not, it will assign the numbers 1 through n to the x-coordinate.

For using `Plot`, the "resolution" of the plot can be changed by adjusting `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`. This code shows what happens as you change those values. The black points are the points that `Plot` is using to draw the curve. Of course, in your final plot you probably won't want to show those black dots. They will only show up if you have some specification for `Mesh`.

```
TableForm[
  Table[
    Plot[
      Sin[x],
      {x, -10, 10},
      Mesh -> All,
      MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[3], Black],
      PlotPoints -> i,
      MaxRecursion -> j
    ],
    {i, 2, 18, 4},
    {j, 1, 5, 1}
  ],
  TableHeadings -> {
    Table[Rotate["PlotPoints \[Rule] " <> ToString[i], \[Pi]/2], {i, 2, 18, 4}], 
    Table["Max Recursion \[Rule] " <> ToString[j], {j, 1, 5, 1}]
  }
]
```

[image: Grid of different PlotPoints and MaxRecursion values.]

Comment: Great... Thank you Sir... This was the answer I was searching for. Thanks a lot